# How to make bootstrap columns divs float/not clear other divs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The current HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="definition col-md-4">
          [Term, definition, etc, in here] 
       </div>
       <div class="definition col-md-4">
          [Term, definition, etc, in here] 
       </div>
       <div class="definition col-md-4">
          [Term, definition, etc, in here] 
       </div>
       <div class="definition col-md-4">
          [Term, definition, etc, in here] 
       </div>
       <div class="definition col-md-4">
          [Term, definition, etc, in here] 
       </div>
       <div class="definition col-md-4">
          [Term, definition, etc, in here] 
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

However as you can see, occasionally the divs don't float up against the divs above them. What's the best approach to make these just snap into columns?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort of layout you are describing is often referred to as the "Pinterest layout" or the "Masonry layout." Bootstrap, out of the box, is not built for this. I would suggest using the [Masonry library](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to create this layout, but if you are set on using Bootstrap, there is a CSS3 solution to make Bootstrap behave this way [here](http://www.bootply.com/118335). Note that if you use the Bootstrap solution, it requires CSS3 properties that are [not supported by older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-width).

Essentially, it uses the [column-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-width.asp) and [column-gap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-gap.asp) properties to set up the columns rather than the CSS styles bundled with Bootstrap.

Comment: That doesn't work since each column is of varying heights.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the question, basically you're wanting to mimic the Pinterest layout using Bootstrap? There's a solution for that here: http://www.bootply.com/118335

Comment: Yes! I'll take a look at that but looks promising. That would be the correct answer if you want to updated it.

Comment: Answer updated, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: So I've been testing this out and those column properties prioritize vertical over horizontal. Seems like it should go left to right, no?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this CSS3 spec was designed to work like a newspaper, where the columns would stack top to bottom first and then left to right. I don't believe there is a property to adjust the way this is handled so you would either need to format your HTML with this in mind or switch to a library that was designed for this sort of layout such as [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html)